# Can a 3-way relationship be modeled this way in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A User can have many roles, but only one role per Brand.

```
Class User < AR::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => "user_brand_roles"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :brands, :join_table => "user_brand_roles"
end
```

The problem with this setup is, how do I check the brand and the role at the same time?

Or would I better off with a BrandRole model where different roles can be set up for each Brand, and then be able to assign a user to a BrandRole?

Class User < AR::Base
       has_many :user_brand_roles
       has_many :brand_roles, :through => :user_brand_roles
   end

Class BrandRole < AR::Base
     belongs_to :brand
     belongs_to :role
    end

Class UserBrandRole < AR::Base
       belongs_to :brand_role
       belongs_to :user
   end

This way I could do a find on the brand for the user:

```
br = current_user.brand_roles.where(:brand_id => @brand.id).includes(:brand_role)
if br.blank? or br.role != ADMIN
  # reject access, redirect
end
```

This is a new application and I'm trying to learn from past mistakes and stick to the Rails Way. Am I making any bad assumptions or design decisions here?

Comment: First please describe what you are trying to accomplish because it doesn't sound like you understand how to create associations. Then it will be much easier to help you :)

Comment: Thanks Sam. I understand relationships in Rails, but I think my confusion level is one step before that. I don't know if I'm asking the right questions. I'm trying to set up a situation where a user can access a protected area of a site with a certain set of permissions. A company has several brands, each of which contain multiple products. Some employees need to see only general information about products within a brand, some need admin-level access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Roles,Brands are reference tables. You can have a single association table **Responsibilities** with columns **user_id, role_id, brand_id**.
Then you can define

```
Class User < AR::Base
 has_many : responsibilities
 has_many :roles, :through => responsibilities
 has_many :brands,:through => responsibilities
end
Class Responsibility < AR::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :role
 has_one :brand
end
```

The you can define

```
Class User < AR::Base
  def has_access?(brand)
     responsibility = responsibilities.where(:brand => brand)
     responsibility and responsibility.role == ADMIN
  end
end
```

[Not sure if Responsibility is the term used in your domain, but use a domain term instead of calling it as user_brand_role]

Answer (score 0):

This is a conceptual thing. If BrandRole is an entity for your application, then your approach should work. If BrandRole is not an entity by itself in your app, then maybe you can create a UserBrandRole model:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :user_brand_roles
end

class Brand < AR::Base
  has_many :user_brand_roles
end

class Role < AR::Base
  has_many :user_brand_roles
end

class UserBrandRole < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :role
  validates_uniqueness_of :role_id, :scope => [:user_id, :brand_id]
end
```